# Write query with subquery in CodeIgniter4 Query Builder?

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter-4

I have the following query which has an issue with Query Builder.

```sql
SELECT IIF(ISNULL(MAX(CODCLIENTE), 0) + 1 = 1,
       (SELECT VALOR + 1
        FROM PARAMETROS
        WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBCLAVE)) = 'MINIM'
          AND USUARIO = '1'),
           ISNULL(MAX(CODCLIENTE), 0) + 1)
FROM CLIENTES
WHERE CODCLIENTE >= (SELECT VALOR
                     FROM PARAMETROS
                     WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBCLAVE)) = 'MINIM'
                       AND USUARIO = '1')
  AND CODCLIENTE <= (SELECT VALOR
                     FROM PARAMETROS
                     WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBCLAVE)) = 'MAXIM'
                       AND USUARIO = '1');
```

Is there any way to do it with Query Builder? I'm currently using this method.

Comment: Why are you using `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` in your `WHERE`? Their use will make the query non-SARGable. Trailing spaces aren't considered by SQL Server for equality anyway (making the `RTRIM` pointless) and if your value has leading spaces *should* it really be equal to a value without them? If it should, then I would suggest your data is the issue, and you should be removing the leading spaces from the actual data.

Comment: Not to mention that `ISNULL` also shouldn't be in your `WHERE`. Use strict boolean logic with `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: is that it serves to bring the last number that follows to assign a user,
the problem is that it did work in the sql server but they asked me to pass it to codeigniter and I don't know how to do it

Comment: [Result Arrays](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-arrays)